# reading and printing inputs and C-string in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, c-strings

I have a simple program to read and echoed the user's input and calculate the total amount. I'm having trouble with arrays. I want to know how to use an array to read and print each product name and the cost and the find grand total upon checkout. Should I also use functions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_CHAR = 100;

void pause();

int main()
{
    char productName[MAX_CHAR]; 
    double price;
    char reply;
    double total = 0;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Welcome to your shopping calculator!" << endl;

    do {
        cout << "Enter the product name: ";
        cin.get(productName, MAX_CHAR, '\n');
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');

        cout << "Enter the amount: $";
        cin >> price;
            while (!cin) {
                  cin.clear();
                  cin.ignore(100, '\n');

                  cout << "Invalid amount. Please enter the amount: $";
                  cin >> price;
            }
            cin.ignore(100, '\n');

         cout << "The product name is" << " " << productName << " "
              << " and it costs" << " " << "$" << price << endl;

         total += price;
         cout << "The total amount is " << " " << total << endl; //program needs to keep a running total

         cout << "Would you like to continue shopping? (y/n): ";
         cin >> reply;
         cin.ignore(100, '\n');

     } while ( reply == 'Y' || reply == 'y');   //the program will continue until the user wants to checkout

   pause();
   return 0;
}

 void pause()
 {
  char ch;

   cout << "Press q followed by Enter key to continue....." << endl;
   cin >> ch;
  }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In order to dynamically add elements to an array, you wold need to use `std::vector`. You can read about them [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). As far as printing your array is concerned, you would have to iterate through it with a `for` loop.

Comment: Is this code not doing what you want?

Comment: At first glance, there's nothing catastrophically wrong with this. What issue are you having? Is this code not working how you want it to?

Comment: @ Carpetfizz Thanks for your help. I am not familiar with vectors but I will take a look at it.

Comment: @0x499602D2 and Keeler - There's nothing wrong with the code. I thought to include the source code to give an idea of what my program is about. I would like to know how to be able to display all the product names, the cost and the grand total upon user's checkout. Thank You.

Comment: I made an answer in response. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track. I think you are mixing I/O conventions in C and C++ which is causing a lot of your issues. It would be very helpful if you could elaborate on what exactly your issues are.

Carpetfizz is correct in that since you don't know the number of items at compile time, you will need to use a dynamic array with `std::vector`. You can learn about vectors [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector).

In addition, C++ has a very useful string data type that you can include with `#include <string>`. Using this, as well as a junk string such as `string junk;`, you can avoid using `cin.ignore(...)` and get cleaner I/O by using `getline(cin, junk)`.

I strongly recommend doing this because creating a vector of C-strings or C-style strings is a pain, because C-style strings are actually arrays of characters, so you'd have to use `std::vector<std::vector<char> >` products.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<char> >` -> `std::vector<const char*>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<const char[]>>`; not that much pain as you might imagine

Answer (score 1):

You need to map the product name to the cost using `std::map` so that you can print the respective pairs afterwards. As for the grand total, that's stored in the variable `total` so printing it is trivial.

To do this, you will need to include the `<map>` header, as the Standard Library class `std::map` is defined there. Moreover, I've also included some changes to your code that should be considered. In particular, using `std::string` and using `std::numeric_limits<...>::max()` to return the constant.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::string productName; 
    double price;
    char reply;
    double total = 0;
    std::map<std::string, double> productToPrice;

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::showpoint << std::setprecision(2);
    std::cout << "Welcome to your shopping calculator!" << std::endl;

    while ((std::cin >> reply) && (reply == 'y' || reply == 'Y'))
    {
        cout << "Enter the product name: ";
        std::cin >> productName;

        cout << "Enter the amount: $";
        while (!(cin >> price))
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Invalid amount. Please enter the amount: $";

        }
        total += price;
        productToPrice.insert(std::make_pair(productName, price));

        cout << "Would you like to continue shopping? (y/n): ";
    }
    ...
}
```

Note the changes I made. Please use them.

To print you simply do:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, double>::const_iterator iter_type;
for (iter_type beg(productToPrice.begin()),
               end(productToPrice.end()); beg != end; ++beg)
{
    std::cout << beg.first << " -- " << beg.second << std::endl;
}

std::cout << "\nThe total price is: " << total;
```